# Reference request-Abstract algebra

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

I need a good book to study abstract algebra (group,ring, field) from basic.I have artin's , rotman's and dummit and Foote in my mind. But Artin's book is somewhat hard for me to understand. Please suggest me which of the above books explain group theory   from basic. 
 But please be specific...I am already confused.. please help me.

Comment: [I find this a good place to begin](http://www.amazon.in/Contemporary-Abstract-Algebra-Joseph-Gallian/dp/1133599702)

Comment: I already saw that.but my question is specific @ AOrtiz

Comment: You might find it useful to use several books at the same time. That way you will see several ways to approach the same material. Comparing them may help you understand that material.

Answer (score 1):

According to me you should prefer "Abstract Algebra" by I.H. seth, well explained topics in that book.

Answer (score 1):

My favourite book in this field is "Abstract Algebra" by I. N. Herstein.
A pdf copy is available here: http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/fawaz/343/Books/Herstein-3thEditon.pdf